# fb.authorize() never give a login event

Tags: facebook, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using the code from the appcelerator docs like this:

```
var fb = require('facebook');

fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {

    Ti.API.info("Login event received...");

    if (e.success) {
        alert('login from uid: '+e.uid+', name: '+ JSON.parse(e.data).name);
    }
    else if (e.cancelled) {
        // user cancelled
        alert('cancelled');
    }
    else {
        alert(e.error);
    }
});

Ti.API.info("fb authorize...");
fb.permissions = ['public_profile'];
fb.initialize();
fb.authorize();
```

But the login event is never fired and nothing happens. Anyone have any idea why?

I am using appcelerator studio 5.2.2.GA and iOS 9.3.1 on iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Please read [Additional iOS Setup Steps](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook) and initialize module:

```
var fb = require('facebook');
 fb.permissions = [FACEBOOK_APP_PERMISSIONS];
 fb.initialize();
 fb.authorize()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I fixed it by adding this line before fb.authorize()

```
var fbBtn = fb.createLoginButton();
```

But I never add the button to the UI, just calling that method seems to trigger something.

Comment: Hmm i still get hung on never receiving the login event.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on physical device or in simulator? Running in simulator can cause such issue, when it will work perfectly on physical device.

Comment: I am testing it on my device. iPhone with ios 9.3.1